# How are custom sails types implemented to behave transparently?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, custom-type

I have to store Decimal in sails.  I want the Decimal type to store a Decimal value as a string, but come back from the store as a Decimal.  I looked at the docs, but all it demonstrates is validation.

Comment: Can't you use the `float` type? ([docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes))

Comment: No, I can't use floats.  Many financial and health and science related issues require the use of numbers that can be as big or small as needed, without any lose of precision and the ability to do exact equality comparisons.  Floats don't offer this level of precision, which is exactly why Decimal aka BigDecimal exists.

Comment: Which adapter are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure that the adapter is relevant.  End target is a combination, dev target is sails-disk.  I don't want a db specific solution, I need a sails solution.